# A method that checks if a String consists of certain characters

Tags: java, string, methods, character

I need to make a method that checks if a given String only consists of lower- and uppercase letters, numbers, dots (.), hyphens (-) and underscores ( ).

```
public boolean isValidString(String name) {

}
```

I just don't know how to get it started :(

Tx in advance

Comment: One general way of handling these sorts of straightforward string-analysis problems is through regular expressions.

Comment: This seems to be homework; if it is, please tag it as such. And don't expect us to do your entire homework for you, but we'll gladly help if you are willing to do some effort yourself. Do you have _any_ idea of what might be involved in solving this? Or have you tried solving a simpler version of the problem; for instance: what would you do if you just needed to check if the string _starts_ with a dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
String s = "Your_string-123.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\.|\\-|_)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
  System.out.println(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Quick tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard library functions.

```
IsLetter()
IsDigit()
IsWhiteSpace()
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using this Regex,

```
str.matches("([A-Za-z0-9.\\-_])+")
```

### Example:

```
public boolean isValidString(String name) {
    return name.matches("([A-Za-z0-9.\\-_])+");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Covert String toCharArray, and then with `foreach` check each `char` wether it is from ASCII set you need